# Why can't a variable defined ina try block be used in catch and finally?

Tags: javascript

The program is running abnormally. The set variable cannot run normally in the module. How to solve it?

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

It can if you declare it with `var`. `const` and `let` are block scoped (in this case, the try block), so you can't access them outside of it.

```
try {
    var a = 2;
    throw "oh no";
} catch {
    console.log(a) // 2
} finally {
    console.log(a) // 2
}
```